# The Big-O of the following equation

Tags: math, big-o, complexity-theory

How to get the upper bound of the following equation, thanks!

2log(mn/2) + 4log(mn/4) + ... + mlog(mn/m)

Comment: Pretty straight forward to show `O(mlog(mn))` and `Omega(mlogn)`, if that help. But I am unsure how to pinpoint the tight bound though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sum works out to **Θ(m log n)**.

Let's start by rewriting

> 2<sup>k</sup> log (mn / 2<sup>k</sup>) = 2<sup>k</sup>(log mn - k)

Now, we have the sum

> Σ<sub>k=1</sub><sup>log m</sup> 2<sup>k</sup> (log mn - k)
>
> = Σ<sub>k=1</sub><sup>log m</sup> (2<sup>k</sup> log mn - k 2<sup>k</sup>)
>
> = log mn Σ<sub>k=1</sub><sup>log m</sup> 2<sup>k</sup> - Σ<sub>k=1</sub><sup>log m</sup> k 2<sup>k</sup>

That first sum is the sum of a geometric series. It simplifies to 2<sup>1 + log m</sup> - 2 = 2m - 2. That means that we're left with

> 2m log mn - 2log mn - Σ<sub>k=1</sub><sup>log m</sup> k 2<sup>k</sup>

That leaves us with the task of simplifying the sum k2<sup>k</sup> over some range. This is an [arithmetico-geometric sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence). If we imagine this sum ranging from 2 (inclusive) to some upper bound q, then the sum works out to q2<sup>q+1</sup>.

> (q+1)2<sup>q+1</sup> - 2 + 2(2 - 2<sup>q+1</sup>)
>
> = (q+1)2<sup>q+1</sup> - 2 + 4 - 2·2<sup>q+1</sup>
>
> = (q - 1)2<sup>q+1</sup> + 2

You can check that this formula is correct by plugging in different values of q.

In our case, q = log m, so the sum we want works out to

> (log m - 1)2<sup>1 + log m</sup> + 2
>
> = (log m - 1)(2m) + 2
>
> = 2m log m - 2m + 2

So our overall sum works out to

> 2m log mn - 2log mn - Σ<sub>k=1</sub><sup>log mn</sup> k 2<sup>k</sup>
>
> = 2m log mn - 2log mn - (2m log m - 2m + 2)
>
> = 2m log mn - 2log mn - 2m log m + 2m - 2
>
> = 2m (log mn - log m + 1) - 2log mn - 2
>
> = 2m (log n + 1) - 2 log mn - 2
>
> **Θ(m log n)**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't realize two types of geometric series in it